# Called function play out ahead of my main code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have two files. One with a game with an evil gambler and the other with a loading function to play out between the lines of text. My goal is to replace the time.sleep() functions with my loading function. The first file looks like this:

```
import random
import time
import test

def game():
    string_o = "Opponent "
    string_u = "User "
    input_n = ""

    input_n = input('Care to try your luck?\n')

    while input_n == 'yes' or input_n == 'y':
        cpu = random.randint(1,6)
        user = random.randint(1,6)
        time.sleep(0.5) 
        print('\nGreat!')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        input_n=input("\nAre you ready?\n")
        time.sleep(0.4)
        print(string_o , cpu)

        #If the gambler's die roll is above three he gets very happy
        if cpu > 3:
            print('Heh, this looks good') 
            time.sleep(0.2)

        #...but if it's lower he gets very anxious
        else:
            ('Oh, no!')     

        test.animate()

        print(string_u , user)

        if cpu < user:
            print('Teach me, master')
        else:
            print('Heh, better luck next time, kid')
            time.sleep()

        input_n = input('\nDo you want to try again?\n')

    print("Heh, didn't think so.\nPlease leave some room for thr big boys")

game()
```

The other file looks like this:

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

done = False
#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
t.start()

#would like an x here instead that is defined in the other file
time.sleep(1)
done = True
```

The problem is that the function animate() plays out before the game has even started.

I would also like to set the time for the loading function in my main game file. Is that possible?

Comment: Which module gets executed first?  What's your command line?

Comment: You really don't want or need to use a thread here.

Comment: The terminal? The output is firstly the loading function and then the game

Comment: What should I use instead? Please enlighten me. I'm a total noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `t.start()` outside of any function in your `test.py`, you are running `animate` as soon as you import `test.py`. You should put `t.start()` inside a function instead. Also, your `done` flag is also set to `True` when `test.py` is imported and will always immediately break your `for` loop inside `animate`. I don't think you really need this flag at all. Change your `test.py` to:

```
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        sys.stdout.write('\rloading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rDone!     ')

    def start():
        t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
        t.start()
```

And then in your first file, instead of calling `test.animate()` directly, call `test.start()` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything at all now. I put the start function in the second file and kept the animate function intact. Then I put the start function in the game file, replacing every time.sleep().The loading file is not working now

Comment: Not sure why you are replacing `time.sleep()` with `test.start()`, since they do completely different things. Did you try replacing `test.animate()` with `test.start()`?

Comment: My main goal was replacing the time.sleep() with the loading animation. So first off I replaced the time.sleep() with test.animate(), but now I replaced time.sleep() with test.start(). The animation in the second file is not executing

Comment: I see. That's because your `done` flag is set to `True` when `test.py` is imported and is breaking your `for` loop immediately. I don't think you should use this flag at all. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Now it prints. I just have to tweak it to make it fit